# macOS Terminal profiles reset after each Terminal restart

Tags: macos, terminal

I am trying to customize macOS's Terminal.app profiles.

Strange thing is, each time I restart the terminal all changes are lost.

What is the macOS way to keep the changes permanent?

Screenshot after I modify the preferences:

[image: After modification screenshot.]

Screenshot after restart the terminal:

[image: After restart screenshot.]

Where is that save button?

Comment: The settings look the same to me in both screenshots. What is your issue?

Comment: What version of macOS? If you create a new clean user account on your system and do the same thing from that account, does the problem happen there as well? When you say "terminal restart", do you mean quitting and re-launching the Terminal app?

Comment: @Spiff the version is macOS Catalina 10.15.5.  And yes terminal restart is quitting and relaunching the terminal. (My user is a clean user.)

Comment: @DavidPostill The issue is after I quit terminal all the changes that I make in the profiles are lost.

Comment: Same issue with macOS 12.4

Answer (score 1):

**Please file a bug to Apple and reference: FB9496089**

It seems like a bug on Big Sur 11.4 (and earlier). All my settings disappear if I quit Terminal.

I submitted Feedback to Apple:

**Terminal Loses all Profile changes and font settings on Quit**

Steps

1. Duplicate Basic profile
2. Make font size 16
3. Make it default
4. Open new terminal window and verify new font size
5. Quit Terminal

Steps (Alt)

1. Adjust Basic Profile from 11 pt to 16 pt font
2. Quit Terminal